# R- visNetwork - graph doesn't show edges

Tags: r, csv, graph, visnetwork

I have a code that looks like this:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Evangelista/Desktop/v1")

require(visNetwork)
require(dplyr)
require(shiny)
require(magrittr)

graf.info = read.csv("nodes.csv")
id <- rownames(graf.info)
graf.info <- (cbind(id=id, graf.info))
graf.powiazania = read.csv("edges.csv")

visNetworkNodes <- data.frame(graf.info) %>%
  mutate(id=graf.info$id,
         label = nazwa_agenta,
         title = nazwa_agenta)

visNetworkLinks <- data.frame(from = graf.powiazania$From,
                              to = graf.powiazania$To,
                              width = 50,
                              arrows = list(to = list(enabled = TRUE, scaleFactor = 4)))

net <- visNetwork(nodes = visNetworkNodes,
                  edges = visNetworkLinks,
                  height = "600px",
                  width = "800px")

net
```

And my problem is that the graph doesn't display any edges. My data is taken from csv file and it looks like this: 
[image: Nodes]

[image]

I don't know what is wrong with it. My data looks correct to me, data frame with nodes also has the column id. Data frame with edges has "From" and "To" columns. I run out of ideas what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
visNetworkNodes <- data.frame(graf.info) %>%
  mutate(id=graf.info$nazwa_agenta, <------here i changed 'id' to 'nazwa_agenta'
         label = nazwa_agenta,
         title = nazwa_agenta)
```